# Apply force to object through plugin

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

is there a way to apply a force to objects/models.

There is "SetLinearAccel", but I can't find any command for applying a force.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23773/apply-force-to-object-through-plugin/) by [lolistic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16127/lolistic/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From my own experience, it seems like the answer is that one can't apply force to a model/object, only a link. This can be solved by getting the desired link from the model, where the names of the links can be changed in the .world file:

`this->model->GetLink("body")->SetForce(ignition::math::Vector3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);`

The same goes for applying torque:

`this->model->GetLink("body")->SetTorque(1.0, ignition::math::Vector3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);`

Hope this helps someone else.

---

Originally posted by [lolistic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16127/lolistic/) with karma: 1 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joshua658413](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34098/joshua658413/) on 2020-12-07**:
Extremely helpful, my slight variation is below

```
this->model->GetLink("link_name")->SetForce(ignition::math::Vector3d(forceX, forceY, forceZ));
this->model->GetJoint("joint_name")->SetForce(0, torque);
```

One thing that was very hard to find anywhere is how to apply a torque to a link. It's done the same way as a force, but Gazebo knows what to do when "SetForce" is done on a joint (revolute joint in my case). The "0" within SetForce() is the axis index, which I think could be non